# What is the difference between an exploit and a compromise?

Tags: security, exploit

I see the words compromise and exploit being used interchangeably. When I did basic Google searches for this question, the answers were about the difference between an exploit and a vulnerability, not the comparison I queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploit: software that makes use of a flaw of the operating system or host software to gain some kind of a benefit.

Compromise: the act of damaging the integrity, confidentiality or availability of a computer; for example, through an exploit.